# Switching system("clear") to goto(int x, int y) to better the performence

Tags: c++

I'm working on a terminal visualizer in C++ (ncurses by a noob xoxo).
I'm inserting frames into a queue and then print them in sequence and adding a sleep in between frames so it would look like an animation, current I'm using system("clear") (I'm on linux swap to system("cls") for Windows) and it is working fine with with frames up to certain size, on bigger frames I encountered printing issues it flickers because it just does not print fast enough, I tried switching to using an escape sequence to move the cursor to a "pixel" that has changed and update it instead of clearing the entire screen and reprinting it only for like 5 pixels that has changed (pixels are characters).

It not exactly not works but it's acting weird, at this point I should mention I animate using my visualizer a simulation of falling sand. I spawn a line of sand that drops down and when encounters an obstacle (like the floor or another sand particle  it stops in its tracks. When using the new method of printing the frame while falling the sand goes wild like falls in sort of zigzag pattern or just in a chaotic pattern also for some reason the floor for the sand is higher than printed. It is not supposed to be the falling sand simulation itself I think because when using the system("clear") it works as expected. I know there are other problems with the code but I would like to focus now this current problem, also if you're wondering why not just use ncurses it is because I would like to improve my pure C++ skills so aside from the STL I'm not using any libraries.

```
//graphical_visualizer.hpp
#pragma once

#include <chrono>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

const std::unordered_map<std::string, char const *> colors = {{"red", "\033[31m"}, {"green", "\033[32m"}, {"blue", "\033[34m"}, {"yellow", "\033[33m"}, {"reset", "\033[0m"}};

void gotoxy(size_t x, size_t y);

struct Pixel {
    char character;
    char const *color_code;

    bool operator==(Pixel const &compare);
    bool operator!=(Pixel const &compare);
};

using frame_matrix = std::vector<std::vector<Pixel>>;

class Frame {
private:
    void initialize_frame();

    bool is_valid_input(std::string const &height_start, std::string const &height_length, std::string const &range_start, std::string const &range_length, std::string const &printable_char, std::string const &color);

public:
    frame_matrix current_frame;
    const static size_t AMOUNT_OF_INPUT_OPTIONS = 6;
    const static size_t FRAME_WIDTH = 60;
    const static size_t FRAME_HEIGHT = 20;
    const static char INPUT_DELIMITER = ',';
    const static char BACKGROUND = '#';

    Frame();
    Frame(std::string const &input);

    frame_matrix get_current_frame() const;
    void alter_frame(std::string const &input);
    void set_current_frame(frame_matrix const &new_current_frame);
    void print_frame();
    void print_frame(Frame const &prev_frame);
    bool parse_input(std::string const &input);
};

class GraphicalVisualizer {
private:
    std::queue<Frame> frame_queue;

public:
    GraphicalVisualizer();

    std::queue<Frame> get_frame_queue() const;
    void add_frame(Frame frame);
    void print_sequence(const std::chrono::milliseconds millis);
    void print_sequence_no_clear(const std::chrono::milliseconds millis);
};

// graphical_visualizer.cpp
#include "graphical_visualizer.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

void gotoxy(size_t x, size_t y) {
    std::cout << "\033[" << y << ";" << x << "H";
}

bool Pixel::operator==(Pixel const &compare) {
    return character == compare.character && *color_code == *compare.color_code;
}

bool Pixel::operator!=(Pixel const &compare) {
    return character != compare.character || *color_code != *compare.color_code;
}

Frame::Frame() { initialize_frame(); }

Frame::Frame(const std::string &input) {
    initialize_frame();
    alter_frame(input);
}

frame_matrix Frame::get_current_frame() const { return current_frame; }

void Frame::alter_frame(std::string const &input) {
    if (!parse_input(input))
        std::cout << "Invalid input \n";
}

void Frame::set_current_frame(frame_matrix const &new_current_frame) {
    current_frame = new_current_frame;
}

void Frame::print_frame() {
    for (auto const &line : current_frame) {
        for (auto const &current_pixel : line) {
            std::cout << current_pixel.color_code << current_pixel.character;
            std::cout << colors.at("reset");
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Frame::print_frame(Frame const &prev_frame) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < FRAME_HEIGHT; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < FRAME_WIDTH; ++j) {
            if (current_frame[i][j] != prev_frame.current_frame[i][j]) {
                gotoxy(j, i);
                std::cout << current_frame[i][j].color_code << current_frame[i][j].character;
                std::cout << colors.at("reset");
            }
        }
    }
}

bool Frame::parse_input(std::string const &input) {
    std::stringstream input_stream(input);

    std::string input_sections[AMOUNT_OF_INPUT_OPTIONS];

    size_t input_sections_index = 0;
    while (std::getline(input_stream, input_sections[input_sections_index],
                        INPUT_DELIMITER))
        ++input_sections_index;

    if (!is_valid_input(input_sections[0], input_sections[1], input_sections[2],
                        input_sections[3], input_sections[4],
                        input_sections[5])) {
        return false;
    }

    int height_start = std::stoi(input_sections[0]);

    int height_length = std::stoi(input_sections[1]);

    int range_start = std::stoi(input_sections[2]);

    int range_length = std::stoi(input_sections[3]);

    char const *color = colors.at(input_sections[5]);

    char printable_char = input_sections[4][0]; // should always be a string of length 1

    for (size_t i = height_start; i <= height_start + height_length - 1; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = range_start; j <= range_start + range_length - 1; ++j) {
            current_frame[i][j].character = printable_char;
            current_frame[i][j].color_code = color;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void Frame::initialize_frame() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < FRAME_HEIGHT; ++i) {
        std::vector<Pixel> line;
        line.reserve(FRAME_WIDTH);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < FRAME_WIDTH; ++j)
            line.push_back({BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")});

        current_frame.push_back(line);
    }
}

bool is_a_number(std::string const &number) {
    for (char const &ch : number) {
        if (!std::isdigit(ch))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Frame::is_valid_input(std::string const &height_start, std::string const &height_length, std::string const &range_start, std::string const &range_length, std::string const &printable_char, std::string const &color) {

    auto pos = colors.find(color);

    if (pos == colors.end())
        return false;

    if (!is_a_number(height_start) || !is_a_number(height_start) ||
        !is_a_number(height_start) || !is_a_number(height_start)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (printable_char.size() != 1)
        return false;

    int height_start_int = std::stoi(height_start);
    int height_length_int = std::stoi(height_length);
    int range_start_int = std::stoi(range_start);
    int range_length_int = std::stoi(range_length);

    if (height_start_int < 0 ||
        height_length_int + height_length_int - 1 >= FRAME_HEIGHT ||
        range_start_int < 0 ||
        range_start_int + range_length_int - 1 >= FRAME_WIDTH)
        return false;
    return true;
}

GraphicalVisualizer::GraphicalVisualizer() { frame_queue = {}; }

std::queue<Frame> GraphicalVisualizer::get_frame_queue() const {
    return frame_queue;
}

void GraphicalVisualizer::add_frame(Frame frame) { frame_queue.push(frame); }

void GraphicalVisualizer::print_sequence(const std::chrono::milliseconds millis) {
    std::queue<Frame> local_temp_queue = frame_queue;

    while (local_temp_queue.size() > 1) {

        local_temp_queue.front().print_frame();
        local_temp_queue.pop();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(millis);
        system("clear");
    }

    local_temp_queue.front().print_frame();
    local_temp_queue.pop();
}

void GraphicalVisualizer::print_sequence_no_clear(const std::chrono::milliseconds millis) {
    std::queue<Frame> local_temp_queue = frame_queue;
    local_temp_queue.front().print_frame();
    while (local_temp_queue.size() > 1) {
        Frame last_frame = local_temp_queue.front();
        local_temp_queue.pop();
        local_temp_queue.front().print_frame(last_frame);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(millis);
        // system("clear");
    }

    local_temp_queue.front().print_frame();
    local_temp_queue.pop();
    system("clear");
}

// falling_sand.hpp
#pragma once

#include "graphical_visualizer.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

const char SAND_SHAPE = '@';
const std::string SAND_DEFAULT_COLOR = "red";
const int SAND_BLOCK_AMOUNT = 25;
const int MIN_SAND_LENGTH = 5;
const int MAX_SAND_LENGTH = 50;
const std::chrono::milliseconds millis_per_frame_falling_sand = 100ms;

struct SandBlock {
    int length;
    int starting_position;
    char shape;
    std::string color;
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> links;

    SandBlock();
    SandBlock(std::string color);
};

class FallingSand {
private:
    Frame field;
    GraphicalVisualizer visualizer;
    std::queue<SandBlock> sand_blocks;

public:
    FallingSand();
    void generate_sand_blocks();
    void simulate_fall();
    void simualte_diag_fall();

    Frame get_field() const;
};

//falling_sand.cpp
#include "falling_sand.hpp"

#include <random>

int generate_random_length() {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(MIN_SAND_LENGTH, MAX_SAND_LENGTH); // distribution in range [MIN_SAND_LENGTH, MAX_SAND_LENGTH]

    return dist(rng);
}

int generate_random_start_pos(int sand_length) {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0, Frame::FRAME_WIDTH - sand_length);

    return dist(rng);
}

SandBlock::SandBlock() {
    length = generate_random_length();
    starting_position = generate_random_start_pos(length);
    shape = SAND_SHAPE;
    color = SAND_DEFAULT_COLOR;
    for (size_t i = starting_position; i <= starting_position + length - 1; ++i) {
        links.push_back({0, i});
    }
}

SandBlock::SandBlock(std::string color) : color(color) {
    length = generate_random_length();
    starting_position = generate_random_start_pos(length);
    shape = SAND_SHAPE;
    for (size_t i = starting_position; i <= starting_position + length - 1; ++i) {
        links.push_back({0, i});
    }
}

FallingSand::FallingSand() {
    generate_sand_blocks();
    // simulate_fall();
    simualte_diag_fall();
    visualizer.print_sequence_no_clear(millis_per_frame_falling_sand);
}

void FallingSand::generate_sand_blocks() {
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= SAND_BLOCK_AMOUNT; ++i) {

        sand_blocks.push(SandBlock());
    }
}

void FallingSand::simulate_fall() {

    while (!sand_blocks.empty()) {
        SandBlock current_block = sand_blocks.front();

        bool did_move = true;
        while (did_move) {
            did_move = false;
            visualizer.add_frame(field);
            std::vector<size_t> links_to_remove;
            frame_matrix new_frame = field.get_current_frame();

            for (size_t i = 0; i < current_block.links.size(); ++i) {
                std::pair<size_t, size_t> link = current_block.links[i];
                if (link.first != Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second].character != current_block.shape) {
                    did_move = true;
                    new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
                    current_block.links[i].first += 1;
                    new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {current_block.shape, colors.at(current_block.color)};
                }
            }

            field.set_current_frame(new_frame);
        }
        sand_blocks.pop();
    }
}

int generate_random_direction() {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0, 1);

    return dist(rng);
}

void FallingSand::simualte_diag_fall() {
    while (!sand_blocks.empty()) {
        SandBlock current_block = sand_blocks.front();

        bool did_move = true;
        while (did_move) {
            did_move = false;
            visualizer.add_frame(field);
            std::vector<size_t> links_to_remove;
            frame_matrix new_frame = field.get_current_frame();

            for (size_t i = 0; i < current_block.links.size(); ++i) {
                std::pair<size_t, size_t> link = current_block.links[i];
                if (link.first != Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second].character != current_block.shape) {
                    did_move = true;
                    new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
                    current_block.links[i].first += 1;

                    new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {current_block.shape, colors.at(current_block.color)};
                } else if (link.first != Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second].character == current_block.shape) {

                    int direction = generate_random_direction();
                    if (link.second != Frame::FRAME_WIDTH - 1 && direction == 1 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second + 1].character != current_block.shape) {
                        new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
                        current_block.links[i].first += 1;
                        current_block.links[i].second += 1;
                        new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {current_block.shape, colors.at(current_block.color)};
                    } else if (link.second != 0 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second - 1].character != current_block.shape) {
                        new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
                        current_block.links[i].first += 1;
                        current_block.links[i].second -= 1;
                        new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {current_block.shape, colors.at(current_block.color)};
                    }
                }
            }

            field.set_current_frame(new_frame);
        }
        sand_blocks.pop();
    }
}

Frame FallingSand::get_field() const {
    return field;
}
```

Here I have 2 variations of simulating falling sand, one is used to simulate falling down and the other simulates falling diagonally if the sand particle encounters another it falls randomly to the left or right if there is an empty place for it to fall there.

And that's it to run it use the constructors for falling_sand and it should run.

Comment: I didn't find the quesiton. For sophisticated screen in/output you can use ncurses though

Comment: *I would like to improve my pure C++ skills* -- Clearing the screen is not "pure C++", as clearing the screen is OS dependent.

Comment: `system("clear")` is very OS-specific. And there's no "goto" function in standard C++.

Comment: "why not just use ncurses it is because I would like to improve my pure C++ skills " well... pure C++ has no way to do what you want. Using escape sequences is a hack, its not portable.

Comment: I can understand where this motivation is coming from, but rather than limiting yourself you need to understand that part of learning is to learn what is the best tool for a given task. ncurses is the defacto standard when it comes to text-only terminal stuff.

Comment: *also if you're wondering why not just use ncurses* -- Nothing stops you from getting the source code for ncurses and see *how* it's done.  Just because you don't want to use a library doesn't mean you will lose face by looking at the source code (assuming the source is available) of the library to see how the library accomplishes the goal you are trying to seek.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah I understand what you're saying the part where I said I want to improve my pure C++ skills is not exactly why I didn't want to use ncurses, it is more like I didn't want to use ncurses because I created a dumbed down version of ncurses so it wouldn't make much sense to me to use it, I should look at the source code of ncurses though, thanks for the advice.
Edit: grammar

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah the title isn't very good sorry, I did mention that I use linux and provided the windows one, I also implemented goto I assumed people will understand that I tried to implement it shouldn't have assumed and am sorry

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai huh I didn't know escape sequences are not portable

Comment: You can replace the call to `clear` with the escape sequence `\033[2J` (or possibly `3J`, depending on your terminal)

Comment: `*color_code == *compare.color_code;` Are you comparing only the first character? It this intentional? `*"red" == *"reset"` are going to be equal `'r' == 'r'`. Use `strcmp`, or just use `std::string` or use `std::string_view`. Right?

Comment: @Ellie it depends on the terminal you are using. ncurses has functions to query what features are supported by the terminal and which not.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: **ncurses** uses the terminfo database to use the correct escape sequences for whatever terminal is being used.  Different terminals have different escape sequences.  Some terminals have almost but not quite the same escape sequences, just to make things more interesting.

Comment: @KamilCuk that was it, can't belive I missed that, thanks a lot! there is still for some reason to rows that are considered below the ground for some reason, but the simulation works.